# Creating Circular flow charts (circos)

Tags: charts, visualization

I'm looking for an app to create charts like the one in the picture. I been using gephi and trying to use circos. Gephi is still on beta and circos needs a lot of configuration in order to get the chart. I'm looking for something easier that could convert a csv file into a chart like this.

[image: circular flow chart]

Comment: It seems that the software in http://circos.ca/ does exactly what you want.  Have you tried it?

Comment: I'm trying the same thing...did you ever find a solution, or did you learn to manipulate Circos? (I'm trying Circlize and Circos in R...as well as Gephi and yEd Graph Editor)

Comment: I found a circos script but I couldn't find a simple tool to do this. You?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In Python, you can use

1. `CircosPlot` from [nxviz](https://github.com/ericmjl/nxviz) (used to be [circos](https://github.com/ericmjl/Circos)).  This is developed by [Eric Ma](https://github.com/ericmjl) on top of Matplotlib.  Note that the documentation seems minimal but as Eric is not paid for this (and is a PhD student) I am sure he would appreciate help improving the docs.
2. `Chord` provided by [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/charts.html#chord) looks great but I am not sure how simple it is to adjust how it displays (note that the `box_zoom` tool creates visual distortions, turn this off
   by [specifying the plot tools](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/tools.html#specifying-tools) using the kwarg `tools='pan,wheel_soom,save,reset'`)
3. [plotly](https://plot.ly/python/chord-diagram/)

In R, you can use

1. [`chordDiagram`](http://zuguang.de/circlize_book/book/the-chorddiagram-function.html) from the [`circlize`](https://github.com/jokergoo/circlize) package
2. `chorddiag` from the [`chorddiag`](https://github.com/mattflor/chorddiag) package

Comment: Wow, thank you very much for this response. I asked this questions two years ago and I haven't been in need of this charts but since there are new tools for doing this I may try to use it in some of my projects. I can imagine some are recent tools and others not. I knew plotly but didn't know they supported this kind of charts. I assume they introduced it in the last years. Thanks again ! 